# Extract feed author in blogger

Tags: blogger

How can I extract a feed author (in a multi author blog) in blogger?

I'm looking for everywhere but I think is impossible. Do you know a trick?

The only way is javascript or JSON, or both. Blogger doesn't support "author" value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to get normal JSON feed and filter author name using JavaScript

```
fetch('/feeds/posts/default?alt=json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    var authorPosts = data.feed.entry.filter(e => e.author[0].name.$t === "AuthorName");
})
```